# Why doesn't the text in svg show up?

Tags: svg

I have a simple svg element,

```
<svg height="100" width="710">
  <rect width="700" height="50"/>
    <rect width="70" height="50" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);">
      <text y="0" style="fill: white;">-0.123994</text>
    </rect>
    <rect width="70" height="50" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);" transform="translate(630,0)">
    <text y="50">0.387869</text>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Why don't either of the `text` elements show up? This is what it shows:
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can not put `text` tag within `rect` . If you want to display text inside a rect element you should put them both in a group.

```
<svg height="100" width="710">
    <g>
    <rect width="70" height="50" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></rect>
      <text y="0" style="fill: white;">-0.123994</text>
    </g>
    <g>
    <rect width="70" height="50" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);" transform="translate(630,0)"></rect>
    <text y="50">0.387869</text>
   </g>

</svg>
```

Please adjust the coordinates of text to show up within rect.

Comment: For me this was part of this answer but I also needed to convert my text object to a path, then ungroup the two objects and delete the one I was no longer using:
https://daviesmediadesign.com/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-circle-in-inkscape/